# PHP, MySQL get "max_updates" value from database

Tags: php, mysql, limit

I got error code (checked via `mysqli_error($link)`):

```
User 'user1' has exceeded the 'max_updates' resource (current value: 35000)
```

However, for other SQL servers, how do I get this value (max_updates) *without* exceeding the quota (here:35000) ?

And when will there be a reset on this ?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-resources.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems like on your host you have some restrictions on MySQL server usage. This does not mean necessarily `UPDATE` statements - but almost any statements. This limit can be hourly, daily, etc. My advise would be to change your hosting provider - these days it's full of cheap high quality hosting and even cloud VPS that won't have any restrictions on specific software usage.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I am going to compare some providers...

And yes, I can confirm this limit goes for `create`, `update`, `insert`, etc...

I do not ask for some specific recommendation, but how do I know whether the provider has any limits on any server usage? Oftentimes, the only limits mentioned are those about traffic, webspace and mailspace.

Comment: For example if you get a cloud VPS you only get resource limits (memory, cpu, storage). Read the terms of service of the provider - I can not guess. DigitalOcean have VPS from $5, there are other cheap alternatives I think.